# Exponential backoff for business exceptions when using reactive spring-amqp?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-amqp, project-reactor

I'm using Spring AMQP 2.1.6 and Spring Boot 2.1.5 and I'm looking for the recommended way to configure spring-amqp to retry business exceptions for reactive components (`Mono`) with exponential backoff. For example:

```java
@RabbitListener
public Mono<Void> myListener(MyMessage myMessage) {
    Mono<Void> mono = myService.doSomething(myMessage);
    return mono;
}
```

I'd like spring-amqp to retry automatically if `doSomething` returns an error. Usually one can configure this for blocking RabbitListener's when setting up the container factory:

```java
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
...
factory.setAdviceChain(retryInterceptor(..));
```

Where `retryInterceptor` might be defined like this:

```java
private static RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor(long backoffInitialInterval, double backoffMultiplier, long backoffMaxInterval, int maxAttempts) {
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(backoffInitialInterval);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(backoffMultiplier);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(backoffMaxInterval);

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy((new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts)));
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean bean = new StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean();
    bean.setRetryOperations(retryTemplate);
    return bean.getObject();
}
```

But the advice chain doesn't seem to be used for reactive RabbitListener's. This is probably because, if I understand it correctly, the `RetryTemplate`/`ExponentialBackOffPolicy` actually blocks the thread.

As a workaround I could of course do something like (switching to Kotlin because it's a bit easier):

```
@RabbitListener
fun myListener(MyMessage myMessage) : Mono<Void> {
    return myService.doSomething(myMessage)
                    .retryExponentialBackoff(10, Duration.ofMillis(100), Duration.ofSeconds(5)) { ctx ->
            log.info("Caught exception ${ctx.exception()}")
        }
}
```

But I'd like this retry logic to be applied to for all instances of `Mono` returned from `RabbitListener`'s. Is something like this possible or should you configure this another way when using reactive sequences from project reactor with spring-amqp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really better to apply retry logic into your reactive sequence, similar way you do with the `retryExponentialBackoff()`. Just because the Reactive Streams execution doesn't happen on the same thread we can apply that `Retrytemplate` for the `myListener()`.

Right now the logic internally is like this:

```
private static class MonoHandler {

    static boolean isMono(Object result) {
        return result instanceof Mono;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static void subscribe(Object returnValue, Consumer<? super Object> success,
            Consumer<? super Throwable> failure) {

        ((Mono<? super Object>) returnValue).subscribe(success, failure);
    }

}
```

That `Consumer<? super Throwable> failure` does this:

```
private void asyncFailure(Message request, Channel channel, Throwable t) {
    this.logger.error("Future or Mono was completed with an exception for " + request, t);
    try {
        channel.basicNack(request.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false, true);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        this.logger.error("Failed to nack message", e);
    }
}
```

So, we don't have any way to to initiate that `RetryTemplate` at all, but at the same time with an explicit `basicNack()` we have a natural retry with the re-fetching the same message from the RabbitMQ back.

We could probably apply a Reactor retry for that `Mono` internally, but it doesn't look like `RetryOperationsInterceptor` can simply be converted to the `Mono.retry()`.

So, in other words, the `RetryOperationsInterceptor` is a wrong way for reactive processing. Use `Mono.retry()` explicitly in your own code.

You may expose some common utility method and apply it as a `Mono.transform(Function<? super Mono<T>, ? extends Publisher<V>> transformer)` whenever you have a reactive return for the `@RabbitListener` method.

Comment: There is some discussion about adding reactor capabilities to spring-retry, [but it doesn't seem to have had much progress](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/92).